# How to work with LWUIT TABs click events

Tags: java-me, lwuit

**UPDATE:**
My Requirement is to display  two  Rss files as Tabs on my LWUIT Form
Initially by default  first Rss file titles and images should be displayed on first tab
if an end user click on second tab,we should be able to load the second rss file titles and images
I am able to load first Rss File titles,but i am not able to load the second  tab if i click on it
How to capture the click event for LWUIT Tab?
Here my code which is not working:
String topNewsurl="TopNews.rss";
String topStoryurl="TopStory.rss";

```
public class XMLMidlet extends MIDlet{
    public void startApp() {
               Display.init(this);

        Process p;
        try {
            p = new Process(this);
                    p.process();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



 public class Process extends Form {


     Process(XMLMidlet midlet) throws IOException {
               this.midlet=midlet;
               topnews = new Vector();
            topstory = new Vector();
           tabs = new Tabs();
            form1 = new Form();
            form2=new Form();
                form1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                form1.setScrollable(false);
                image = Image.createImage("/res/Tone.jpg");
                Label icon = new Label(image);
                form1.setTitleComponent(icon);
                form2.setTitleComponent(icon);

                form1.setTransitionInAnimator(Transition3D.createRotation(250, true));
                try {
                newsList = new List(topnews);
                newsList.setScrollVisible(false);

                newsList.setRenderer(new NewsListCellRenderer());

                myNewsList = new List(topstory);
                myNewsList.setScrollVisible(false);

                myNewsList.setRenderer(new NewsListCellRenderer());        
         tabs.addTab("Topstory", newsList);
                tabs.addTab("TopNews", myNewsList);
                 tabs.setChangeTabOnFocus(true);
               form1.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, tabs);
        }  
     try{
String url = "http:topnews-20.rss";




             form1.show();


                        ParseThread myThread = new ParseThread(this);
            myThread.getXMLFeed(url);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public void addNews(News newsItem) {
        //log.debug("addnews");
      //System.out.println("addNews");

            topnews.addElement(newsItem);
            newsList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                    List source = (List) ae.getSource();
                    News selectedNewsItem = (News) source.getSelectedItem();
                    if (selectedNewsItem != null) {
                        displayCompleteNewsScreen(selectedNewsItem);

                    }

                }


            });
        form1.show();


    } 


     public void keyReleased(int keyCode) {
                   System.out.println("str");

            Component p=this.getFocused();
           String str= p.getClass().getName();
        if(str.toLowerCase().indexOf("radiobutton")!=-1){
            process();
        }
```

Comment: What you are trying to do and the code you pasted are incoherent. Could you clarify? You speak of LWUIT tabs but are not using the tabbed pane UI. What do you refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the very vague question it seems you want to capture key presses on a LWUIT Form.

```
        jobsForm.addGameKeyListener(Display.GAME_FIRE,
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    //do something here
                    }
                });

        jobsForm.addPointerPressedListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                pointer_click = true;
            }
        });

        jobsForm.addPointerReleasedListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (pointer_click) {
                    //
                }
                pointer_click = false;
            }
        });

        jobsForm.addPointerDraggedListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                //System.out.println("POINTER DRAGGED");
                pointer_click = false;
            }
        });
```